# Python import google.oauth2.credentials ImportError: No module named google.oauth2.credentials

Tags: python

i'm trying to run this bot https://github.com/ItsCEED/Youtube-Comment-Bot
in mac os but i get this error

```
l:Youtube-Comment-Bot-master ROOTXX$ python yt.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yt.py", line 6, in <module>
    import google.oauth2.credentials
ImportError: No module named google.oauth2.credentials
l:Youtube-Comment-Bot-master ROOTXX$
```

Comment: `google` is not a standard library package. Did you install the Google Python API libraries?

Comment: The page you link to has a list of requirements, including *A YouTube API (I show how to get one in the video, it's really easy)*, as well as a list of modules you need to have installed. Did you follow those instructions?

Comment: A quick google led me to https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation, perhaps that'd be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 3):

Run in a root terminal:

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

From [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/apis/oauth2/v1), found with a google search.

EDIT: Even better, you linked the required libraries yourself. They are in the GitHub README.md at [here](https://github.com/ItsCEED/Youtube-Comment-Bot). Please read your own links. Anyway, the commands to install follow:

```
# pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
# pip install --upgrade requests
# pip install --upgrade beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: `random` is a standard library, do not install it with pip. `bs4` is the module installed by the `beautifulsoup4` project, use the latter, not `bs4`. The `google-api-python-client` package *includes* the other `google` modules.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't proofread, obviously never reinstall random :). I don't know about google-api-python-client package, but if you says so. bs4 I was able to install with the command in my answer, please could you explain to me the difference?

Comment: Hrm, I may be wrong about the `google-auth` and `google-auth-oauth` packages; the API client does include OAuth2 support but the linked project decided to use another package instead. The OP will next discover that they need to register with Google and download a JSON file that the script will try to read, etc.

Comment: Ah, `google-auth` is a dependency for `google-auth-oauth`, so no need to install the former separately. And the [BeautifulSoup authors have `bs4` covered these days](https://pypi.org/project/bs4/).